# Core Data repository is empty when used in XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios9, xctest

in a XCTest class I get the managed object context like this:

```
//setup Core Data Stack
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FabApp" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
NSError *error = nil;
XCTAssertTrue([psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error] ? YES : NO, @"Should be able to add in-memory store");


self.moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
self.moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
```

the ManagedObejctContex is created successfully but when I try to fetch some entities it does not find any. I am 100% sure that this entities exist in Core Data as I use them in the app

```
- (void) testAllInputIsSavedInCoreData{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employ"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:_moc];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [_moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    XCTAssertEqual([[_lines objectAtIndex:0] count], [results count],@"Missmatch in saved data read %lu but saved %lu",(unsigned long)[[_lines objectAtIndex:0] count], (unsigned long)[results count]);
}
```

how is that possible, am I missing something?

Comment: have you tried deleting your project app in the simulator and running it again?

Comment: Yes, right now. It didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an in-memory persistent store (`NSInMemoryStoreType`) instead of SQLite (or XML). Everything "stored" in the in-memory store is not written to a sqlite database, it only exists until the context is deallocated which happens every time you setup your stack.

When writing Unit Tests, you typically want this behavior because you don't want to store extra objects in Core Data every time you run your tests.

Comment: How can I test that the Application wrote correctly on Core Data

Comment: The Core Data stack should work as you expect if as long as you don't recreate/deallocate the moc

Comment: Actually I want to test the behaviour of a method of AppDelegate (in which I write objects in Core Data) as a black box. I don't want to call that method in XCTest. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If I want to test the method I should pass a reference to the new moc I created in XCTest...

Comment: Exactly, the term for that is dependency injection which makes testing a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that the test modelURL is the same as the app modelURL
2. Check that the test MOM is not nil
3. `addPersistentStoreWithType:::::` returns the store or nil (not a BOOL)
4. You are using an in-memory store PSC (which is not persisted)
5. In your test, are you adding entities to the in-memory store first?
6. `[[_lines objectAtIndex:0] count]` doesn't look right and it's not referenced previously in your `testAllInputIsSavedInCoreData` method.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, checked and OK. 6 is ok too. 4 and 5 in my test I am not actually adding objects in Core Data, I do it in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate.